# how to writer after insert triggers to insert data into another table based on the values of first table

Tags: mysql, triggers

I want to create a trigger after insert on one table which would insert values into another table based upon the values of the first table.Here is what i have done and its not working.

```
CREATE TRIGGER add_into_alerts
AFTER INSERT ON in_sims_responses
FOR EACH ROW 
IF new.sim_response_code='102'
THEN
INSERT INTO bf_alters(company_id,description,event_datetime)
VALUES (NEW.sim_company_id,CONCAT(new.sim_msisdn,'Not Subscribed'),NOW());
END IF
```

Comment: What is the problem exactly? It looks reasonable except for the syntax errors.

Comment: @Vatev syntax error near end IF AT LINE 8

Comment: Try adding the `BEGIN` (after FOR EACH ROW) and `END` (at the end) statements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For multiple-statements triggers you need to wrap your statements between `BEGIN` and `END`. But you can avoid that by making it a single-statement trigger. In your case you can use a conditional insert:

```
INSERT INTO bf_alters(company_id,description,event_datetime)
    SELECT NEW.sim_company_id, CONCAT(new.sim_msisdn,'Not Subscribed'),NOW()
    FROM dual
    WHERE new.sim_response_code='102';
```